# If $G$ is a group and $\mathrm{End}(G) \cong \mathbb{Z},$ why is $G$ Hopfian?

Tags: abelian-groups, hopfian

This is supposed to be well-known and easy to establish. If $G$ is Hopfian, then any surjective endomorphism $f:G \rightarrow G$ must be an automorphism, hence a unit in the endomorphism ring, hence correspond to a unit of $\mathbb{Z}.$ So, $f$ corresponds to $\pm 1.$ That is, $f$ is $\pm 1_G$, $1_G$ being the identity function on $G.$ Is this the correct approach to take?

Comment: If you're trying to prove that $G$ is Hopfian, why do you start out by assuming that?

Comment: @anomaly - You're correct. I doubt this approach will work because it neglects to address the fact that there may yet be other endomorphisms that are surjective. It seems that all endomorphisms are essentially multiplication by an integer, but I have been unable to exploit this so far. It is embarrassing to be hung up on what is supposed to be an easy argument.